# MYSQL - Count total of rows from multiple tables with same column name

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: a_survey, b_survey and c_survey. Each of these tables have a column_name "user_id". What I want to do is count the actual posted surveys and return that value in a single row. So, if there was found one record with the matching user_id for each of these tables, the count would return 3.

Here's what I've tried:

```
select count(user_id) AS total_of_surveys 
  FROM a.survey, b.survey, c.survey 
 WHERE user_id = 3;
```

but I'm getting error:

```
Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the ambiguity. And read about joins. And generally familiarise yourself with the workings of SQL. Have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have tried was a cartesian plan it will multiply the result by the quantity of registries on each table.

The right way to do what you want is to join (with left join) or 'UNION' the tables like:

```
select count(user_id) from
(select user_id from a_survey where user_id = 3 UNION ALL
select user_id from b_survey where user_id = 3  UNION ALL
select user_id from c_survey where user_id = 3) tables
```

Comment: Thank you, this was IMO the best and most simple answer :) I will accept this within minutes!

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum(count(a.survey.user_id)+count(b.survey.user_id)+count(c.survey.user_id)) AS total_of_surveys 
  FROM a.survey, b.survey, c.survey 
 WHERE user_id = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to count each table seperately and sum it together. You can do this with one (ugly) query if you want. Something like this should work:

```
Select (select  count(user_id) FROM a.survey WHERE user_id = 3) + (select  count(user_id) FROM b.survey WHERE user_id = 3) + (select  count(user_id) FROM c.survey WHERE user_id = 3) as total_of_surveys;
```